# SQL Server 2016 filter inside json_value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a `feeds` table with a json array column (`UserLike`) of people who like it. Table will be like:

```
FeedID  FeedName    UserLike
 1       Feed 1      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"},{"UserID":2,"UserName":"User 2"},...]
 2       Feed 2      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"},{"UserID":2,"UserName":"User 2"},...]
 3       Feed 3      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"}]
```

I want to get list of feeds and exactly like info of user login by compare `UserID` (if he has liked, or not return UserLike null, i want to get feed row even if login user is not in `UserLike` list).

How can I do it? Does T-SQL support some thing like:

```
select 
    FeedID, FeedName, 
    Json_value(UserLike, '$[UserID=1].UserName')...
```

The result that i'm expecting is:

```
FeedID  FeedName    UserID  UserName
1       Feed 1      2       User 2
2       Feed 2      2       User 2
3       Feed 3      NULL    NULL
```

with WHERE clause: UserID=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Here we take all feeds
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT FeedID,
                FeedName
FROM dbo.feeds
--Here we take parsed JSON
), feeds AS (
SELECT  FeedID,
        FeedName,
        UserID,
        UserName
FROM [dbo].[feeds] f
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ([UserLike]) 
WITH (
    UserID int,
    UserName nvarchar(255)
))
--And here we join them
SELECT c.FeedID,
        c.FeedName,
        f.UserID,
        f.UserName
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN feeds f
    ON f.FeedID = c.FeedID and f.UserID = 2
```

Output:

```
FeedID  FeedName    UserID  UserName
1       Feed 1      2       User 2
2       Feed 2      2       User 2
3       Feed 3      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: hi @gofr1: First, thank you so much for your answer.
Second, sorry i'm not writting clearly table structure. It must be like this <br />
`FeedID  FeedName    UserLike
 1       Feed 1      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"},{"UserID":2,"UserName":"User 2"},...]
 2       Feed 2      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"},{"UserID":2,"UserName":"User 2"},...]
 3       Feed 3      [{"UserID":1,"UserName":"User 1"}]`
<br />

Comment: Please, edit your question, this code hard to read from comments.

Comment: hi @gofr1: First, thank you so much for your answer.
Second, sorry i'm not writting clearly table structure. It have fixed in my post.
So, i have try to use `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(UserLike)`. But the thing is, the record without `UserID` of login user in `UserLike' will not show. And the list returned is not excally what i want. I want to get feeds list, and the info if i have liked it or not. Add WHERE statement after cross apply openjson will make me miss some records. Do you have any advice, or am i doing wrong ?? Thank you very much !!  

Sorry, my first time post in stack :).

Comment: Hey, I changed my post. I assume you have some table with all users? If so join it with the query from my answer on `UserID`. If I am wrong in my guessing than, please, add what output you want to get.